# How add rows to select/dropdown dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, html-select

I have a select dropdown for returnreasons that is populated from DB. If user is in specific role he can add new reasons. The problem is that my model in dropdown is not updating automatically after adding? The adding goes to DB though, but in the view dropdown is not populated again even if the model has changed.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedReason">
    <option ng-selected="{{reason.returnreasonId === selectedReason}}"
        ng-repeat="reason in returnreasons"
        value="{{reason.returnreasonId}}">
        {{reason.returnText}}
    </option>
</select>

<div class="form-group form-group-lg" ng-show="addReasonToggle">

    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">New reason:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="returnReason.returnText" placeholder="New reason for return">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" ng-click="addNewReturnReason(returnReason)">Lisää</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In controller**

```
$scope.addNewReturnReason = function(returnReason){
                    var savedReturnReason = [];
                    if (returnReason === undefined || returnReason === null) {
                        console.log("returnReason null");
                    } else {
                        // This is default value
                        returnReason.languageLanguageId = $scope.languages[0];
                        savedReturnReason = returnReasonSvc.save({}, returnReason);
                        savedReturnReason.$promise.then(function (result) {
                            $scope.returnReason = result;
                            $scope.returnreasons = returnReasonSvc.query();
                            $scope.addReasonToggle = false;
                            $scope.selectedReason=savedReturnReason;
                        });
                    };

                }
```

Comment: what browser you use? Update of dropdown data should work in chrome, you need workarounf for IE thow.

Comment: I use Chrome. I ended up to use push and it works now: $scope.returnreasons.push(savedReturnReason); but  $scope.selectedReason=savedReturnReason this is not working :( So the last added element is not automatically selected. Any idea for that?

Comment: You'd better use ng-options. Usual way is saving object to server and adding it manually to array u have. (You do not need usually to reload all array from server)

Comment: I think that I tried it but couldn't get it working: if you have time, could you show me a working demo? I added $scope.selectedReason.push(savedReturnReason.returnreasonId) as well and now the correct selection flashed, but only flashed and then it goes back to blanc.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/92xAVL6aJDWamTs784vy

Comment: Now I found the culprit. I took promise.then off and It started to work! Thank you @PetrAveryanov very much. savedReturnReason.$promise.then(function (result) {...

Answer (score -1):

Could be a problem of watch cycle is not running you can try this in your **then** function..

```
$scope.$apply();
```

to run manually .hope so it will work .

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, but no luck.